# BUG in .NET MAUI Android App freshly created

Tags: android, .net-maui

I'm running VS Community 2022 Preview Version 17.3.0 Preview 2.0

I created a new .NET MAUI App using the Template.

When I run it under Windows, the button that you are supposed to click correctly says how many times it has been clicked after you click it.

But, when I run it under Android emulator Pixel 2 Pie 9.0, and I click the button, it just says "Clicked". It does NOT say how many times.

Answer (score -1):

It is a known issue in android.And we will see a fix in the next release.

You can follow up the relative issues here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8136

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8028